# RoR - Devise: User not logged in when signing up through nested form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I need some help with a RoR application I'm working on. So far it's a pretty simple application and I'm using Devise for authentication.

My application has 2 models, User and Partner. When a Partner creates a new account their 'partner' details are saved to the Partner table and their 'user' details (in this case email and password) to the User table. I did this by creating a form (partners/new) which has a nested form for users.

**Partner View new.html.erb**

```
<%= f.inputs do %>
  <%= f.input :name %>
  <%= f.semantic_fields_for :user do |t| %>
    <%= t.input :email %>
    <%= t.input :password %>
    <%= t.input :password_confirmation %>
  <% end %>
  <%= f.input :telephone %>
  <%= f.input :address %>
  <%= f.input :payout_details %>
  <%= f.input :preferred_payment %>
  <%= f.input :terms_and_conditions, :as => :boolean %>
<% end %>
```

**Partner Model partner.rb**

```
after_initialize :create_user
def create_user
  self.user ||= User.new
  self.user.roles = "partner"
end
```

**Partner Controller**

```
class PartnersController < ApplicationController
  # GET /partners
  def index
    @partners = Partner.all
  end

  # GET /partners/1
  def show
    @partner = Partner.find(params[:id])
  end

  # GET /partners/new
  def new
    @partner = Partner.new
  end

  # GET /partners/1/edit
  def edit
    @partner = Partner.find(params[:id])
  end

  # POST /partners
  def create
    @partner = Partner.new(params[:partner])
    sign_in @partner.user

    respond_to do |format|
      if @partner.save
        format.html { redirect_to @partner, notice: 'Partner was successfully created.' }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
      end
    end
  end

  # PUT /partners/1
  def update
    @partner = Partner.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @partner.update_attributes(params[:partner])
        format.html { redirect_to @partner, notice: 'Partner was successfully updated.' }
      else
        format.html { render action: "edit" }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /partners/1
  def destroy
    @partner = Partner.find(params[:id])
    @partner.destroy

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to partners_url }
    end
  end
end
```

The issue I'm having is although a new partner is created and saved to both the User and Partner tables, they're not automatically logged in like they are when you create a new user through the usual Devise route of users/sign_in.

Could anyone explain where I'm going wrong or what I'm missing?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your controller, are you doing:

```
sign_in @partner.user
```

UPDATE

```
def create
  @partner = Partner.new(params[:partner])

  respond_to do |format|
    if @partner.save
      sign_in @partner.user
      format.html { redirect_to @partner, notice: 'Partner was successfully created.' }
    else
      format.html { render action: "new" }
    end
  end
```

Comment: No, just tried adding this to the create action in my Partner controller but still no luck

Comment: add your partner controller code. Also, make sure that the models are being persisted

Comment: Have added my Partner controller code. When you say are my models persisted I'm not sure what you mean (Rails newbie here), sorry. Thanks for your help though.

Comment: Sorry just re-added it to the create action

Comment: @ChrisArnold Updated with the sign_in in the correct place (only after it's been saved)

Comment: Ahhh I see, that makes sense now! Thanks @JesseWolgamott, appreciate your help.